# Битрикс. Проблема с базой данных

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет. Поставил Битрикс на Open Server. При проверке системы выдает ошибку: Ошибочный ответ сервера. Не удалось завершить тестирование! Все обрывается на 62%

[image: БД1]

В каталоге не работает меню с товарами

[image: БД2]

В файле /bitrix/modules/main/install/mysql/install.sql записано все правильно. Кто знает как решить эти проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

По вопросу ошибки структуры БД при проверке - там указано, что ошибочный ответ сервера, т.е. либо сервер упал при запросе, либо, по какой-то причине ответ некорректный пришел, либо еще что-то. Я бы начал изучение с просмотра логов сервера в OpenServer.

По второму скриншоту - могу предположить, что используется связка Apache + Nginx, а в конфиге Nginx по умолчанию в OpenServer все файлы с точкой в начале блокируются (из-за этого не работают некоторые css-стили Битрикса). Нужно открыть конфиг Nginx, выбрать файл который заканчивается на _vhostn.conf, и там убрать соответствующее правило, например:

```
# Disable access to hidden files/folders
if ($uri ~* /\.(?!well-known)) {
    return 404;
}
```

После этого перезапустить.

Answer (score 0):

У меня всё было установлено на HDD диске, он был намного медленнее SDD. Когда я переустановил всё заново на SDD, то ошибка исчезла